# Store .css('display') value and return it on other page button click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this rather simple section on my website, that has few divs with anchor boxes in them. After clicking one of the anchors, the div is hidden and another div shows up. Some of these anchor boxes are links to other pages on my website. I also have a back button which shows the last visible div. Here is a very detailed jsfiddle I've made - https://jsfiddle.net/wy5kzv7d/17/.

Anchors with class `.box.link` lead to a new page, while if the anchor has only `.box` it hides the current wrapper and shows other.

Is there a way to remember which divs were hidden and which were shown when using the backbutton or clicking a link after going to a new page? I've tried to use http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/, but the documentation is kind of bad and it was last updated 8 years ago, unfortunately I cannot manage to make it work. I'm also not really sure if this is even the lib I need to use.

**Edit 1:** I've found this JSFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/hut65tja/1/ and tried to implement it to my code, but it doesn't work right. How to make the global show limited to `$(this)`? Here's a new JSfiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/wy5kzv7d/19/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var show = sessionStorage.getItem('show');

  if(show === 'true'){
    $('.level').css('display', 'flex').hide().delay(150).fadeIn();
  }

  $('.box').click(function () {
    event.preventDefault();

    // If it is not end point (link) always hide it's parent
    if (!$(this).hasClass('link')) {
        $(this).parent('.level').fadeOut(150);
        sessionStorage.setItem('show', 'false');
    }

    const goDeeper = `.${$(this)[0].classList[0]}-wrapper`;
    // console.log(goDeeper);
    $(goDeeper).css('display', 'flex').hide().delay(150).fadeIn();
    sessionStorage.setItem('show', 'true');

  });

  // Back Button JQuery
  $('.catalog-back-button').click(function () {
    if ($('.level3').is(':visible')) {

        $('.level3').hide();
        $('.level2.mebeli-wrapper').delay(100).fadeIn();

    } else if ($('.level2').is(':visible')) {

        $('.level2').hide();
        $('.level1').delay(100).fadeIn();

    }
  });

});
```

Comment: Use localstorage because you need a place to store your information.

Comment: Store the state somewhere. localstorage, cookies, etc. In this case I would use the hash fragment of the url as the idea is specifically to 'link' to a different page state. `http://myserver/myapp/mypage#box1`

Comment: @Shilly, could you check check edit and just give me a direction to take.